# fdisk: unsupported wipe mode

Tags: files, filesystems, partition, lvm, data-recovery

I am trying to create a new partition
fdisk -W /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var but keep getting

> fdisk: unsupported wipe mode

```
nvmeVg-var is a part of an lvm
```

When I

```
fdisk /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var
```

I get

> The device contains 'ext4' signature and it will be removed by a write
> command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.

after pressing g to create a new empty GPT table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is part of `LVM` you should use command

```
lvcreate
```

to create volume/"pattition" in this volume group. And then create filesystem, mount, etc